# Symfony form validation for date fields (sfWidgetFormI18nDate)

Tags: symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.2.9, and I have a form that contains two date fields:

start_date AND end_date.

I want to impose the following validation criteria for the 'start_date' field:

1. i). CANNOT be less than todays date
   ii). CANNOT be greater than end_date
   iii). CANNOT be more than 1 month
   away

For end_date, I want the following restrictions:

2. i). Cannot be more than 3 months
   away from today

I have written a post validator check as follows:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

//post validator check to make sure end date > start date
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
 new sfValidatorAnd(array(
    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('start_date', '<', 'end_date',
      array('throw_global_error' => true),
      array('invalid' => 'The start date ("%left_field%") must be before the end date ("%right_field%")<br />')
       ),

    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('start_date', '<', $today,
      array('throw_global_error' => true),
      array('invalid' => 'The start date ("%left_field%") cannot be earlier than today\'s date: ('.$today.')<br />')
       ),

    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('end_date', '>', $today,
      array('throw_global_error' => true),
      array('invalid' => 'The end date ("%left_field%") cannot be before today\'s date ("%right_field%")<br />')
       )
    )
   )
 );
```

However, this is not working - i.e. I have not found a way yet to enforce restrictions based on todays date, or offsets from today's date.

A solution would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally for code readability I'd move your post validation checks into a postValidate method on your form, vis:

```
public function configure()
{
  // your normal configuration stuff goes here

  // set up your post validator method
  $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
    new sfValidatorCallback(array(
      'callback' => array($this, 'postValidate')
    ))
  );
}
```

Then you can do something like the following:

```
public function postValidate($validator, $values)
{
  $today = date("Y-m-d");

  if (strtotime($values["start_date"]) < strtotime($today))
  {
    $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, "Start date cannot be before than today");
    throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('start_date' => $error));
  }

  if (strtotime($values["start_date"]) > strtotime($values["end_date"]))
  {
    // throw a similar validation error here
  }

  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have two questions:

1. How would you get the 'postValidate' method triggered during form validation?

2. You are not using the validator passed in as an argument, in the pseudocode, it would be useful to see how I could throw a validation error using the passed in validator.

Comment: Edited to explain a bit more :-)

Comment: Thanks very much Ric. Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I will attempt to implement it - if it works, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Rich, I am indebted with you. I almost cant believe it. This is something I have tried to resolve for a *long* (feels like forever). The documentation and online tips etc were of now use. I implemented your suggestion (I must admit, with some scepticm because of my past experiences with this problem - even the SF forum was no help) - but your solution worked. Wow!. I am indebted to you !

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! I'm personally not a fan of the sfValidatorAnd() stuff, particularly when it gets complicated - much prefer to use a custom method, that way I know where everything is :-)